# Not Retrieving Status for Some users FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am unable to retrieve Status using FQL for Some Users...for Most of User it is working fine.. but for Some Users not ...

FYI Message is Public and Visible to all friends.

I unable to find what is the problem...Below is The Query..

```
SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid in (XXXXX,XXXXX)
```

Comment: For your users, is it identical to `me/statuses?limit=1` for the results?

Comment: Do you have the right permissions?  The docs say it doesn't matter if it is public or not.  Are you using the same access token or different for each person?

Comment: Thanks for you reply actually for most of user it working great but for only some user it did not work although that use posted status with public setting in facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Must Need to Allow My Status Update under Privacy Settings>> How You Connect>> How people bring your info to apps they use